# Apache Flink Filter Function

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

i want to implement a custom filter function in Apache Flink but i don't get how i can inject a list of filter conditions into it without hard wiring them.

Let's assume my function looks like this

```
public class CustomFilter implements FilterFunction{

  @Override
  public boolean filter(Object o) throws Exception{
  String[] values = {"First","Second","Last"}; <-- How can i pass this Array or Collection to my Filter function?
     for(String s: values){
        if(!o.toString().contains(s)) return false;
     }
  return true;
  }
}
```

The streaming job will look like this:

```
public class StreamingJob{
...
env 
    .fromElements("Data","New Data","First")
    .filter(new CustomFilter())
    .print
    .execute();
}
```

When i try to add some kind of collection to the CustomFilter function parameters in the class like

```
public boolean filter(String s, Collection<String> searchValues){
    ...
}
```

i get the message that the function has to be from type String only which as it is an implemented function.

Comment: COuld you please explain a bit the issue - where do you get this data from ? SHould it be loaded from somewhere or what ?
Will simply passing it to a constructor of CustomFilter work for you?

Comment: The filter values will be loaded when the job starts. I am totally free in terms of how the solution can look like to pass them into the function but currently i dont understand how to do it as i don't have to pass in the content of the stream into the function but it is already there.

Comment: What's wrong with adding the filter conditions to the constructor?

Comment: To which constructor? I tried to make a constructor for the class CustomFilter but as it implements a functional interface i am not able to access the orignal value that should be filtered anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have noted, just save the list of target values that you pass in via the constructor, and use them in the `filter()` method.

```java
public class CustomFilter implements FilterFunction<Object> {

    private String[] targetValues;

    public CustomFilter(String[] targetValues) {
        this.targetValues = targetValues;
    }


}
```